# Find all the integer pairs $(x,y)$ that satisfy the equation $7x^2-40xy+7y^2=(|x-y|+2)^3$

Tags: number-theory, contest-math, diophantine-equations

Find all the integer pairs $(x,y)$ that satisfy the equation 
$7x^2-40xy+7y^2=(|x-y|+2)^3$

it is clear the equation is symmetric therefore you can assume w.l.o.g that $x\ge y$ which makes the new equation equal to
$(x-y+2)^3=7x^2-40xy+7y^2$

which becomes 
$0=x^3+x^2(-1-3y)+x(12+28y+3y^2)+(8+y^3-y^2-12y)$
but I don't know what to do next , help, suggestions and solutions would be appreciated.
I think Lagrange multipliers can be used but there is a preferred solution that doesn't use calculus.
Taken from the 2019 SAIMC https://chiuchang.org/imc/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2019/08/SAIMC-2019_Keystage-3_Individual_Final.x17381.pdf

Comment: $x=-2,y=2$ or $x=2,y=-2$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First notice that $7x^2-40xy+7y^2\le\frac{27}{2}|x-y|^2$ and equality holds only if $x+y=0$. (You can show this directly by expanding)

Now, let $t=|x-y|$ then $(t+2)^3\le\frac{27}{2}t^2$ and $t\ge 0$.

Since $(t+2)^3-\frac{27}{2}t^2=(t-4)^2(t+\frac{1}{2})$, this holds only if $t=4$, and even when $t=4$, you get equality and this implies $x+y=0$.

Thus, $|x-y|=4$ and $x+y=0$ is the only candidate.

Therefore, the only possible pairs are $(2,-2)$ and $(-2,2)$. (They are actually integer pairs, but even for real number pair we get the same)

Comment: How did you come up with the idea of the first inequality? I can easily verify it myself but I would like to how you came up with it.

Comment: @ViktorGlombik - (|x-y|+2)^3 is cubic term, which grows faster than quadratic terms. Thus, it is natural to try to make a bound on LHS by some quadratic polynomial of |x-y|. In this case, LHS is homogeneous symmetric quadratic form so a|x-y|^2 is a natural one.

Comment: @C.Park but why the coefficient of $\frac{27}{2}$ specifically?

Comment: @ViktorGlombik - That is just what we calculate. I wrote "$a|x-y|^2$", where $a$ is an undetermined coefficient which is in fact $\frac{27}{2}$. To find out $a$, just try to expand it and see when the formula is in squared form.

Comment: @C.Park and where did you get the $(t-4)^2(t+\frac{1}{2})$ from?

Comment: @ViktorGlombik - To be honest, I searched wolfram(...) and that the formula is strictly positive but only at $4$ is a miracle(that is made by the problem maker)

Comment: Even if it had some other values of $t$ that made the function negative, since we only need to consider when $t$ is integer and this is definitely positive for big $t$, I would have divided the problem into some cases and have done slightly more annoying work. (That's what I expected at first glance)